# Access level aware dependency injection into inherited field

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

At work there is a process framework. It uses keys and containers to set parameters without the use of dedicated constructors (it's basically the type safe heterogeneous container pattern).

I recently added dependency injection.
Below you find a representative example (it lacks some null checks, access control, etc.)

```
  private static void inject(Process instance, Container c) throws Exception
  {
    Class<?> reference = instance.getClass();
    for (Field field : reference.getDeclaredFields())
    {
      Inject inject = field.getAnnotation(Inject.class);

      Key<Object> key = new Key<>(inject.key());
      field.set(instance, c.getObject(key));
    }
  }
```

The implementation is working, but now I need to enhance it in order to also inject into inherited fields.

I had no problem retrieving the type hierachy and all the annotated, inherited fields. But in order to comply with Java, I must not inject into every retrieved field.

Only when the field is:

1. `public`
2. `protected`
3. `package-privated` and declared in a class that has the same package as  `reference`
4. `private` and declared in class that encloses `reference`, which has to be an inner class (non-static nested class).

Items 1 - 3 are easy to check for. I have difficulties with the last item. Is there an elegant solution?

I thougt about using `java.lang.Class.isMemberClass()` and comparing class names.

Currently my check looks like this

```
  private static boolean accessAllowed(Class<?> reference, Field field)
  {
    int modifiers = field.getModifiers();

    boolean hasAccess = Modifier.isPublic(modifiers);
    hasAccess |= Modifier.isProtected(modifiers);

    // TODO fix
    hasAccess |= Modifier.isPrivate(modifiers) /* add check as defined in 4. */;

    // no access and not private means field is package-private
    if (!hasAccess && !Modifier.isPrivate(modifiers))
      hasAccess = reference.getPackage().equals(field.getDeclaringClass().getPackage());

    return hasAccess;
  }
```

Is there an easy and/or efficient way to find out whether a class is enclosed by another class? Or is there another way to find out whether I am allowed to inject?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should handle the private case.

The derived class is `reference`, it tries to set members inherited from `fieldDeclaringClass`

```
  static boolean hasPrivateAccessRelation(Class<?> reference, Class<?> fieldDeclaringClass)
  {
    boolean isMemberClass = reference.isMemberClass();
    boolean isEnclosingClass = reference.getName().contains(fieldDeclaringClass.getName());

    // static nested classes can't access private members of enclosing class
    return isMemberClass && isEnclosingClass && !Modifier.isStatic(reference.getModifiers());
  }
```

The code works if the derived class is a **inner class** of `fieldDeclaringClass`. It fails if it is a **static nested classes**, since these have no access to private fields of enclosing classes.

A previous check is necessary to make sure `reference` and `fieldDeclaringClass` are not equal. Because in that case `static` would be a valid modifier, since a nested class always has access to its own fields.